# Cannot send build results to SonarQube server

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm working on a POC and I'm able to create a project and send the build results to SonarQube localhost server without any errors.
But when I build the same project and send the the results to production server, build will succeed but the results on the server is empty.

In the server, I'm getting the following warning.

> SCM provider autodetection failed. Please use “sonar.scm.provider” to define SCM of your project, or disable the SCM Sensor in the project settings.

I found that, its not creating the **output-cs** folder. when i run these commands in local its creating those files and folders but for production server its not.

Path to output-cs

> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my-project.sonarqube\out\0

Code I ran for localhost:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.1.0.28487-net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin 
/k:"my-test-project" /d:sonar.verbose=true /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" 
/d:sonar.login="project-token"

MsBuild.exe /t:Rebuild

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.1.0.28487-net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end 
/d:sonar.login="project-token"
```

Code I ran for Production Sever:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.1.0.28487-net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin 
/k:"my-test-project" /d:sonar.verbose=true /d:sonar.host.url="http://prod-server-url" 
/d:sonar.login="sonarqube_project_token"

MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.1.0.28487-net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end 
/d:sonar.login="sonarqube_project_token"
```

*Difference between those two codes is only the SonarQube project name and token only.*

I went through the build stack trace and found some warnings.

> WARN: No coverage report can be found with
> sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml'.
> Using default locations:
> target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml

Doubt:

1. Do we need to specifically mention some additional parameters when building for server compared to localhost?

Note: This is c# application.

Comment: The coverage and SCM provider are just warnings a far as I know. I would expect a real error if the is an issue.

Comment: @Julian thanks but in the stack trace im not getting any red errors. not sure if im missing any parameters. yet im not getting errors other than those two warnings

Comment: Maybe post the full log of `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot do that due to company rules. is there any parameters i should pass compared to localhost server code? or can we change the MSbuild path or version?